# SQL - Inert row if not exist update row if exist problems

Tags: mysql, sql

So i am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/miah/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert/)

Insted of doing a query like this ("Which i could not get to work either...")

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1='SomeValue')
    UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

I want to do it like this

```
UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

The benefit of doing it like this should be to avoid two index searches.

Table
[image]

SQL

```
UPDATE ctc_portfolio_coins SET (ctc_portfolio_coins_amount = 100) WHERE ctc_portfolio_coins_portfolio_fk = 1
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO ctc_portfolio_coins (ctc_portfolio_coins_portfolio_fk, ctc_portfolio_coins_coin_fk, ctc_portfolio_coins_amount) VALUES (1, 1, 100)
```

Error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ctc_portfolio_coins_amount = 100) WHERE ctc_portfolio_coins_portfolio_fk=1
IF ' at line 1
```

Can anyone tell me what is goin on and maybe tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: "Can anyone tell me what is goin on and maybe tell me what i did wrong" You are going wrong thinking MS-SQL is MySQL server..

Comment: Please share your table as text data tables or as SQL statements (PHPMyAdmin can export the tables as SQL very eazy)..and explain your requirement better instead off not usable SQL code... You are using columns that don't exist in your table..

Comment: What Raymond want to say is that you was following a tutorial from Microsoft for SQL Server, but you are using MySQL. Although SQL is a standard each DB server has different implementations for parts outside the standard (and sometimes they don't fully implement the standard). In this case, the `IF EXISTS()` method and the `@@ROWCOUNT` method only works in SQL Server, and the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` method only works in MySQL/MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to implement the original query in MySQL is to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` along with a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_table1_column1 ON table1(column1);

INSERT INTO table1(col1, . . . )
    VALUES ( . . . )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = VALUES(col1), . . .;
```

You should not be learning the `IF EXISTS` formulation.  It is inferior due to race conditions -- two threads attempting similar operations at the same time.

For your particular query, `@@ROWCOUNT` is not part of MySQL.  You query would be phrased as:

```
INSERT INTO ctc_portfolio_coins (ctc_portfolio_coins_portfolio_fk, ctc_portfolio_coins_coin_fk, ctc_portfolio_coins_amount)
    VALUES (1, 1, 100)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ctc_portfolio_coins_amount = VALUES(ctc_portfolio_coins_amount);
```

This assumes that you have a unique index on the column that you do not want duplicated.

Comment: Okay great thanks for the HU, but im still a bit confused as to how i am going to implement this in my current table ? its not like each row have an unique email field or similair? 1 portfolio can have many different coins?

Comment: This quer

`INSERT INTO ctc_portfolio_coins (ctc_portfolio_coins_portfolio_fk, ctc_portfolio_coins_coin_fk, ctc_portfolio_coins_amount)
    VALUES (1, 1, 100)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ctc_portfolio_coins_amount = VALUES(ctc_portfolio_coins_amount)` is inserting a new row every time it query

Comment: I think its because i need a unique index, currently ctc_portfolio_coins_portfolio_fk can have many coins so that cant be unique, i guess i will need to do 2 unique keys which rely on each other somehow? like ctc_portfolio_coins_portfolio_fk  is unique with ctc_portfolio_coins_coin_fk somehow

Comment: Made it work thanks alot for guiding me in the right direction